# How to set encoding in IntelliJ javadoc generating?

Tags: encoding, intellij-idea, javadoc

While generating javadocs from within IntelliJ I am getting multiple errors for files:

```
unmappable character for encoding Cp1251
```

File encodings are `UTF-8`. I found no any places for encoding control while javadoc generating.

Answer (score 28):

You can pass options to the Javadoc tool from IntelliJ IDEA. Adding `-encoding utf8 -docencoding utf8 -charset utf8` to in the *Other command line arguments* text field should fix your problem. `-encoding` specifies the encoding of the source files. `-docencoding` the encoding of the output html files and `-charset` the charset specified in the html head section of the output files.

Comment: What if source files have different encodings specified in IJ?